# How do I insert this into a table in Oracle APEX?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm trying to insert these values into a table in Oracle APEX and I'm not sure how to enter the LOGIN_DATE_TIME values.

[image]

I have the data type set to DATE for the LOGIN_DATE_TIME column and the values can't be NULL.

For the FACULTY_ID, I have it set to VARCHAR2 and it is also NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You said that `LOGIN_DATE_TIME`'s datatype is `DATE`. Value on the screenshot says `timestamp` so - which one is it, really? Anyway: set item's type to Date Picker and set its format to `dd-mon-yy hh:mi:ss am`.

`FACULTY_ID` is an ordinary Text Item.

Both should be *required* as those columns don't accept `NULL` values.